# Unity Collaborate Error: "It looks like you don't have any data yet"

Tags: unity, tools

On the [Unity Developer page](https://developer.cloud.unity3d.com/), my partner has added me to his team. I can see his project. I clicked `Go to Collaborate`:

[image: Go to Collaborate]

That brings me to the "Assets" tab, saying "It looks like you don't have any data yet."

[image: It looks like you don't have any data yet.]

Clicking on the provided link just brings me back to the main page, where no detailed instructions can be found.

Has anyone successfully used the new "Unity Collaborate" feature yet?

Answer (score 1):

In the top-right of Unity editor you should be able to check your current status with Collaborate.

[image: UnityEditorScreenshot]

Comment: Hi Daniel! Turns out, my `Collab` button is greyed out. Apparently, after signing up, you have to wait to be accepted into the closed beta before you can participate. Apparently we have not yet been accepted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @domi Oh, ok! Sorry to hear that. When got it greyed out it was because I had nothing to commit, but I guess that you'll need to get invited. I hope you get it soon! :)